# if control does not work using check box

Tags: if-statement, checkbox, event-handling, google-apps-script

I cannot manage to handle the 'check-box handler', a problem, that I have traced back to happen obviously within the if-control function.
If you try the following modified code, you see, that the Boolean-variable "e.parameter.myCheckBox" yields the correct result, the if-branching-off based on this variable, however, does not work. Does anyone see the mistake here?

Thank you very much
Martin

```
function ifTest(e) {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('ifTest');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var grid = app.createGrid(3, 3);
  var myCheckBox = app.createCheckBox().setName('myCheckBox').setId('myCheckBox');
  var button =     app.createButton('submit').setId("submit").setWidth("280").setHeight("35");

  grid.setWidget(1, 0, app.createLabel('Check for True').setStyleAttribute("font-size",  "110%"));
  grid.setWidget(1, 1, myCheckBox);
  grid.setWidget(2, 1, button);

  var handler = app.createServerHandler('ifCheck'); 
  var handler = app.createServerClickHandler('ifCheck');
  handler.addCallbackElement(myCheckBox);  
  myCheckBox.setValue(false, false);  

  handler.addCallbackElement(grid);
  button.addClickHandler(handler);

  panel.add(grid);
  app.add(panel);

  ss.show(app);
  return app;
}

function ifCheck(e) {
  var bCBresult = e.parameter.myCheckBox;
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();

  Browser.msgBox(bCBresult);
  if (bCBresult) {    
    Browser.msgBox("bCBresult = true");
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("bCBresult = false");
  };
  return app.close();
}
```

Comment: You should add a tag corresponding to the language you are using.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I have done so.

Comment: What part does not work? Do you only get 1 message box?

Answer (score 0):

the value returned by `e.parameter.myCheckBox` is a string, not a boolean. (that's actually the case for all e.parameter values..., they are always strings)

So your condition would be `if (bCBresult=='true') {`

Comment: It works now. That was exactly the information that I needed.